# Round Robin, confused about how to processes are handled related to arrival order

Tags: process-scheduling

See this picture, in parentheses are (arrival time, execution time required)

[image]

Why doesn't the "p5" process is processed before "p6"? Why do p3 and p4 are finished and p5 is executed only after the processes that arrive at "11" are executed?

Answer (score 1):

In round-robin scheduling, every process is put into a big queue as soon as they arrive. When a process gets to the front of the queue, it is treated for some fixed number of time-steps (in your case 3 steps, as I suppose is also what's meant by the text "Quantum = 3"). If the process is not finished when its time is up, it gets stowed in the back of the queue. So when Process 5 is done at step 12, it gets stowed in the back of the queue, behind all the processes that arrived at step 11.